# Angular cookies not returning same value at different url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

Currently I am implementing angular cookies to retain information. This is the way I add information.
`oItems` is the javascript array of objects.

**Angular Versoin 1.4.7**

> $cookies.putObject("oItems",oItems,[{path:'/',expires:exp,domain:'alpha.domain.com'}])

And the way to get is :

> $cookies.getObject("oItems")

These work fine when I am on url alpha.domain.com

Now I try to access cookie at alpha.domain.com/cart and able to receive values. **The problem comes when I remove element from array** "oItem"
On **alpha.domain.com/cart** it shows one item only where as on **alpha.domain.com** it shows 2 items .

Can you guys please tell me which could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is to set path to "/" so that all actions/urls from your application access and update the same cookie. Simply we have to do:

> myApp.config(['$cookiesProvider',function ($cookiesProvider) {
>       $cookiesProvider.defaults.path = '/';
>   }]);

It took me find to do so but yes, it works.